# Blackberry Bitmap fieldChanged throws IllegalStateException

Tags: blackberry, menuitem, illegalstateexception

I have a bitmap field in my blackberry5 app with fieldChanged listener attached to it which works absolutely fine 
now my problem is that I also have an associated menu for the same purpose (I can not remove it's the requirement) and on click the menu I get a JVM 104 IllegalStateException

here is my menu class

```
 public class TabMenu extends MenuItem{
    MainScreen menuScreen;
    Field button;
    public TabMenu(String menuLabel,MainScreen menuScreen,Field button) 
    {

        super(menuLabel, 1, 0);
        this.menuScreen = menuScreen;
        this.button = button;
    }//end constructor



    public void run() 
    {
        FieldChangeListener listener = (FieldChangeListener)this.menuScreen;
        listener.fieldChanged(this.button, this.button.getIndex());
        this.button.setFocus(); 

    }

 }
```

and here is menu and fieldchnaged code

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
     menu.add(new RefreshMenu()); 
     menu.addSeparator();
     menu.add(new TabMenu("Go >", this, goTab));
     menu.addSeparator();
 } 


  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) { 
    if (field == goTab) { 
       Dialog.alert("goinf") 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Any suggestions, hints or comments please

Comment: and the code inside fieldChanged(Field,Context)

Comment: protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
  
  menu.add(new RefreshMenu());
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.add(new TabMenu("Go >", this, goTab));
  menu.addSeparator();
  
 }


public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
  
 if (field == goTab) 
 {
  Dialog.alert("goinf")
 }
}

Comment: Hard to say what is happening there, but why not write you code so that the button perss and the menu selection eventually call the same method rather than trying to fake out the UI into behaving as if the button had been pressed when the menu is selected?

Comment: what happens if you comment setFocus() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `TabMenu#run()` method to the following:

```
public void run() {
    this.button.fieldChangedNotify(this.button.getIndex());
    this.button.setFocus(); 
}
```